# Error in initializing firebaseAuth in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I started working Firebase on android studio(java). my app break in this line FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
i searched solution in many places everything is correct but again and again getting error in that line

gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.grocereasy'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.grocereasy"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'

}
```

Activity:

```
package com.example.grocereasy;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.Firebase;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button signupBtn;
    EditText name, email, password;
    TextView login;
    FirebaseAuth auth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        signupBtn = findViewById(R.id.signupBtn);
        name = findViewById(R.id.regName);
        email = findViewById(R.id.regEmail);
        password = findViewById(R.id.regPassword);
        login = findViewById(R.id.goToLogin);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });

        signupBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createUser();
            }
        });

    }

    private void createUser(){
        String userName = name.getText().toString();
        String userEmail = email.getText().toString();
        String userPassword = password.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(userName) || TextUtils.isEmpty(userEmail) || TextUtils.isEmpty(userPassword)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fill all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if(userPassword.length() > 6){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Password must be grater then 6 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error: "+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

explain why this error is showing and give any idea to resolve
i searched solution in many places everything is correct but again and again getting error in that line. Please someone explaine this

Comment: Have you added `import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;`? Does it work that way?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.2.0'`

use Firebase Bom

```
dependencies {
  // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.5.0')

  // Declare the dependencies for the desired Firebase products without specifying versions
  // For example, declare the dependencies for Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
}
```

This should fix the issue.

Comment: sorry , not working same error